# Why Connection doesn't have executeQuery method

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc, executequery

Why `executeQuery()` method isn't available in `Connection` Class?

If it was available we can easily call `executeQuery` method using `Connection` Object.

So can't we extend the `Statement` Class to `Connection` Class to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking why the `executeQuery` is in the `Statement` class and not in the `Connection` class??

Comment: yes sir........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It break the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

> principle that states that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class.

Connection class handle connection and doesn't decide/know how to execute the query (single, batch, template...)